# Swipe required before pattern unlock on Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens

I have a pattern screen lock set on Samsung Galaxy S6, and with the Android 6.0 Marshmallow upgrade, I must swipe before I get the pattern.

Can I disable the required swipe, and just open the pattern unlock screen?

Comment: While I'm on Samsung, I don't have a stock Marshmallow installed (having CM13 instead). From the research I did, there seems to be no way to enter the pattern/PIN/password directly without swiping first, if you're on a Samsung stock Android. There may exist a solution, though, if rooting is an option: there's an Xposed module called **XTouchWiz**, which claims to allow you a fair level of customization, while avoiding you to flash another firmware. From the module's feature list, I can see a **"Fast PIN Unlock"**, so it may allow a fast pattern unlock as well. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

### [myLock utilities (Lockscreen improvements)](https://f-droid.org/app/i4nc4mp.myLock)

Does the job for me on my Nexus, Samsung Galaxy, and YotaPhone with Marshmallow and Lollipop. Work without root permission.

### Screenshots:

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm whether this feature would work on your particular ROM but it definitely works for stock Android 5.x and 6.x. You would need a rooted Android, **compatible Xposed Framework installed** and [GravityBox [MM]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox) installed and activated.

In GravityBox, under *Lockscreen tweaks* go to *Direct unlock* and choose *Standard* or *See through*. Select *Default* under *Direct unlock policy*.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

This would make sure to show the unlock phase of lock screen whenever the device is *securely* locked and screen is turned on.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Xposed Framework *for stock Android [based] ROMs*: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

This is by design and cannot be changed without installing a different launcher. Personally, I like the swipe as the lock screen looks neater without the numbers on it all the time.

I think the reason this was done was to accommodate for the new Lollipop lockscreen notifications - instead of displaying in the status bar, they display on the lockscreen. There would be no room for them with a keypad in the way.

Comment: Well if it cant be changed, it is a bad upgrade that needs to be removed as there is now an additional step each and every time the phone locks. On the previous Android platform this was not the case and you were able to directly access the pattern lock, saving an unnecessary step. Upgrades in software are supposed to make the phone easier to use, not add redundancy.