# Skip slide to unlock screen

Tags: lock-screens

Since android 5 I must slide the screen before I'm able to enter the PIN

How to bypass this behavior ?

I am, of course, expecting a "hack", not a vanilla solution

Android 8

Rooted and Xposed

Motorola Moto G6 (XT1925-5)

Comment: GravityBox Xposed module has a feature called "Direct Unlock" (accompanied by "Direct unlock policy"). Enabling it and setting the correct policy would show the security challenge the moment screen is turned on (thus bypassing the need to do swipe). I had tested this with earlier versions and it used to work, but for some reason I can't make it work in Android 9. Maybe give it a try and see if it works for Android 8

Comment: Near duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142129/96277

Comment: Not working, unfortunately. Tried Standard direct unlock and see through. Also tried standard or despite notifications... None. Pin length worked though. It's an addition. Too bad this GravityBox is heavy, or else I'd keep it

Comment: Couldn't find that thread using google or stackexchange's search. All led to stupid tutorials on how to remove security.